# What percentage of the characters in a string are non-english?

Tags: php, character-encoding

Is there a simple way in PHP to tell what percentage of the characters in a string are non-english?

What I'm trying to achieve is detecting non english items in a list based on a description and the percentage is used to account for the special characters that might be present in an english text too. Eg. having a less than 5% non english characters would not necessarily mean that the text is not in english but having 95% non english characters would.

Comment: Use mb_strlen() to get the length of the string; use preg_match() to get a count of the characters [A-Z], and do a bit of math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no direct way of doing it, but this might help using [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Here is an example

```
 $string="string with utf-8 chars åèä - doo-bee doo-bee dooh";
 $utf = mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8') ;
 echo $utf ;
 echo "<br />";
 $all  = strlen($string);
 echo $all ; 
 echo "<br />";
 $non_eng = $all - $utf ; 
 echo $non_eng ;
```

You will have 3 non eng chars and using the total length you can calculate the % .

Answer (score 0):

In the English language you know that we have 26 letters without any diacritical marks (i.e the accents). 
You can either:
1) have a list of letters in both upper and lower case, number characters and any other characters you would like to accept as 'English' stored in an array

2) or do a short cut like this: `$az = range('a', 'z');` which will return all 26 characters, make sure you do the same for capital letters and numbers, and add those elements into one big array.

Then iterate through each letter in your text document comparing it to each letter in your English characters array where you will tally hits and misses as you go through the document.

Then you can work out the  percentage for English letters found in your document by doing the following:

`100/ total number of characters in the document * hits (the total number of English characters found)`